# C++ to C# named pipe hangs on client read

Tags: c#, c++, ipc, named-pipes

C++ named pipe server code

this code is executed once.

```
LPTSTR lpszPipename = "\\\\.\\Pipe\\D2MSPipe";

hPipe = ::CreateNamedPipe(lpszPipename,
                            PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND,
                            PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE,    // | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE,
                            PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,
                            4096,
                            4096,
                            0,
                            NULL);

bool b = ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL);
```

From here, the server waits for the client to connect. Which makes sense.

When the client is connected, here is the C++ code to send data

```
LPTSTR data = "Hello";
DWORD bytesWritten = 0;
WriteFile(hPipe, data, strlen(data) * sizeof(TCHAR), &bytesWritten, NULL);
```

Here, bytesWritten contains 5.

Heres my C# client form

```
using (NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "D2MSPipe", PipeDirection.In))
{
    pipeClient.Connect();

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(pipeClient);

    while (true)
    {

        if (reader.Peek() > -1) { 

            byte[] data = new byte[5];
            try
            {
                int wtf = pipeClient.Read(data, 0, 5);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }

        }
    }

    pipeClient.Close(); // this doesn't make sense but whatever for now.
}

int wtf = pipeClient.Read(data, 0, 5);
```

This line hangs. It doesn't throw an exception.

When I step into this instruction, it just does nothing, the data is never assigned/available in the byte array, the code stops executing.

I've tried multiple way to read, with a stream, with no stream, with ReadLine, ReadToEnd...

Everything hangs.

The client has a while loop because the server is going to send data every minute or so. So I assumed I needed to connect only once and create only one StreamReader and peek in a loop to read the incoming data.

Comment: What do you want to happen instead of "hanging"? I assume you want to continue to wait for data.

Comment: Problem is the data is never avalaible in the byte array. When I step into the line that hangs, it just hangs and never assign the variable. I want it to fill the byte array and eventually continue looping and waiting for the server to send the next message,

Comment: The first read should succeed. Then any further reads are likely to block. Are you sure the first read never completes?